# Как инициализировать структуру в векторе на C++?

Tags: c++, структуры, vector, struct, вектор

Как объявить структуру в структуре, при этом используя вектор?

Делаю так, но не получается

```
struct a {
    std::vector<struct b { int number; };> b;
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем Вам ОБЪЯВЛЯТЬ структуру прямо в векторе? Объявить её нужно заранее, ДО объявления этой структуры, и потом уже использовать её как обычный тип:

```cpp
struct B // Переименовал, потому что имя структуры и имя переменной не могут совпадать
{
    int number; 
};

struct a 
{
    std::vector<B> b;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Определяем структуру `a` с объявленной структурой `b` в шаблонном параметре шаблона вектора:

```
struct a
{
    std::vector<struct b> vec;
};
```

Далее определяем структуру `b`

```
struct b
{
    int i;
    double d;
};
```

И используем

```
a aaa;
b bbb{100, 500.0};
aaa.vec.insert(std::begin(aaa.vec), bbb);
```

Comment: Уберите слово `struct` перед `b` в параметре шаблона и Вы получите мой ответ.

Comment: @V-Mor про перенести определение `b` до определения `а` не забудьте

Comment: Непонятно, в каких файлах что написано. Укажите это более явно

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя определить структуру на месте шаблонного аргумента, но можно на месте типа массива:

```
#include <iostream>

struct a {
    struct b {
        int number = 42;
    } vec[42];
};

int main() {
    std::cout << a{}.vec[7].number << '\n';
}
```